# Sorting Matrix Columns in RDLC Report

Tags: sorting, matrix, rdlc

I get the following query result:

```
EmployeeName    payelement    payelementValue    payelementOrder
------------    ----------    ---------------    ---------------
emp1            PE1           122                2
emp1            PE2           122                1
emp2            PE1           122                2
emp2            PE2           122                1
emp3            PE1           122                2
emp3            PE2           122                1
```

Which results in a report that looks like:

```
Employee Name   PE2     PE1
emp1            122     122
emp2            122     122
emp3            122     122
```

I have created a matrix in rdlc report and and put the column field with the ->'payelement   ' and the value field with ->'payelementValue' and set the rows field with ->'employeeName     ' the problem now is that I want to sort the 'payelement' upon the field named 'payelementOrder' which represents the order for paylements in their actual table while I actually get them sorted alphabetically by defualt i.e.(PE1 then PE2). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you created a matrix you got a Column group. In the group properties of the column group you can set order by specific field (payelementOrder in your case)

Answer (score 2):

I Solved by this...
Go to the .rdlc... Check the **Row Groups**(which we will find in the left-bottom) under of that we will find the grouped column name (which we are having in the tables) then right click on it-> Go to **Group properties...** -> Go to **sorting**-> on the sort by give the column name which you want to sort according to and Click Ok.

And You are Done....